# How to configure comet (comet.ml) to log Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, comet-ml

Im trying to set comet (https://www.comet.ml) to track my Tensorflow experiment, after I create an Experiment and log the data set i dont get the accuracy in my report.

my code:

```
mnist = get_data()
train_step, cross_entropy, accuracy, x, y, y_ = build_model_graph(hyper_params)

experiment = Experiment(api_key="XXXX", log_code=True)
experiment.log_multiple_params(hyper_params)
experiment.log_dataset_hash(mnist)
```

in the example account : https://www.comet.ml/view/Jon-Snow I see that accuracy is reported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can report accuracy using this method:

- `experiment.log_accuracy(train_accuracy)`

take a look at the full Tensorflow example in our guide:

- https://github.com/comet-ml/comet-quickstart-guide/tree/master/tensorflow

Comment: yes! was looking for this, love what you guys are doing!